# Convert to Objective C ARC an osiriX plugin that uses graph kit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, plugins

After changing my OS from snow leopard to mavericks I'm currently trying to convert an old plugin that still uses Garbage Collector to ARC.

The problem is, that plugin is using GraphKit framework, and GRAxes.h has a struct with objects in it.

```
struct {
    NSRect rect;
    NSSize sz;
    NSRect * prect;
    NSArray * arr;
    NSMutableDictionary * md;
    char ch;
} *_extraData;
```

How can I change this ? I don't have any .m and I can't find the GraphKit framework on the internet... I found another one in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks but I can't even access the headers...

It is kind of hard to me to explain my problem I hope you will understand it.

Thank you, Jaak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark specific files as non-ARC in Xcode.

Then you can compile your ARC plugin to use non-ARC frameworks.